# PHP references and pointers

Tags: php, pointers, reference

Is there any difference between pointers and references?
When should I use references?

What actually this syntax does?

```
$a = &$b
```

Comment: That question is about passing by reference to a function. Here is explained the difference between variable, pointer and reference.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not use references!** They can lead to unexpected behavoiur.

As at [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php): *One of the key-points of PHP 5 OOP that is often mentioned is that "objects are passed by references by default". This is not completely true.*

There are pointers and references, you can see it it example below.

- $a = new stdClass ($a now is a **pointer** to #168)
- $b = $a ($b is now a *new* **pointer**, but it still points to #168)
- $c = &$a ($c is now a **reference** to pointer $a)
- you can't distinguish $b from $c
- $a = null, it's just not a pointer anymore, just null
- #168 is kept, because there are pointers to it left
- $b is still a pointer to #168
- $c is now null

This behavior is dangerous, because it alters variable you don't touch.

```
$b === $c // returns true
$youCantSayThisVariableIsRelated = null
$b === $c // returns false!
```

[image]